# How do I remove elements from a list that is in a dictionary, by the dictionary's keys

Tags: c#, algorithm, list, dictionary

This one is kinda long so i put the question on the bottom if you don't think you need context to answer.

I need to calculate which (chess)knights on a board full of only knight attacks other knights and remove the least possible amount of knights so that no one attacks each other.

Input:

```
5
OKOKO
KOOOK
OOKOO
KOOOK
OKOKO
```

The first number is the size of the board (rows and cols),'O'-empty spaces,'K'-knights.

So my idea to do this with just one cycle through the matrix(I want it to be as fast as possible) is to save the knights position and the positions of all the knight that he steps on in a list,in a dictionary like this (the string will be the indexes separated by space):

`Dictionary<string, List<string>> knightsAttacks = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();`
This way i can just count the number of elements in the list and then remove the one with the most indexes in his list, after that i remove, this knights indexes from all the other knights list and if all the lists of all the knights are empty that means that no knights interfere with one another.In this example given above the dictionary will look something like this:
[image]
The selected knight is the one with the biggest count(most hits) so I need to remove him and his index ("2 2") from the other knights lists.
All good and well on theory but i cant execute the removing from the lists part.
This is the code i manged to write so far:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Practice
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            char[,] board = new char[n, n];

            Dictionary<string, List<string>> knightsAttacks = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                char[] line = Console.ReadLine().ToCharArray();
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    board[i, j] = line[j];
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    List<string> list = new List<string>();
                    bool checker = false;
                    int x1 = i + 1, y1 = j + 2;
                    int x2 = i + 1, y2 = j - 2;
                    int x3 = i - 1, y3 = j + 2;
                    int x4 = i - 1, y4 = j - 2;

                    int x5 = i - 2, y5 = j + 1;
                    int x6 = i - 2, y6 = j - 1;
                    int x7 = i + 2, y7 = j + 1;
                    int x8 = i + 2, y8 = j - 1;
                    if (board[i, j] == 'K')
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            if (board[i, j] == board[x1, y1])
                            {
                                
                                list.Add($"{x1} {y1}");
                                checker = true;
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                        }
                        try
                        {
                            if (board[i, j] == board[x2, y2])
                            {
                              
                                list.Add($"{x2} {y2}");
                                checker = true;
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                        }
                        try
                        {
                            if (board[i, j] == board[x3, y3])
                            {
                             
                                list.Add($"{x3} {y3}");
                                checker = true;
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                        }
                        try
                        {
                            if (board[i, j] == board[x4, y4])
                            {
                                
                                list.Add($"{x4} {y4}");
                                checker = true;
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                        }
                        try
                        {
                            if (board[i, j] == board[x5, y5])
                            {
                               
                                list.Add($"{x5} {y5}");
                                checker = true;
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                        }
                        try
                        {
                            if (board[i, j] == board[x6, y6])
                            {
                              
                                list.Add($"{x6} {y6}");
                                checker = true;
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                        }
                        try
                        {
                            if (board[i, j] == board[x7, y7])
                            {
                               
                                list.Add($"{x7} {y7}");
                                checker = true;
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                        }
                        try
                        {
                            if (board[i, j] == board[x8, y8])
                            {
                              
                                list.Add($"{x8} {y8}");
                                checker = true;
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                        }
                    }
                    if (checker)
                    {
                        knightsAttacks[$"{i} {j}"] = list;
                    }
                }
            }
            var theMostHits
                = knightsAttacks.Values.Max( x=> x.Count);


            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**My question:**
After finding the key with the biggest count of elements in its list how do i remove the key's name (in this case "2 2") from the other lists in the dic?

Comment: Looks like a *graph* problem: each knight is a *vertex*, if two kinghts attack each other they are connected by an *edge*… And you are going to find the largest independent subset: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)

Comment: To make that text formated the way you want you can wrap them up in a pair of `<pre></pre>` tags. I updated the question for you. You also can make new lines show up by putting two spaces at the end of a line instead of doing a empty line of space.

Comment: Clean up your code as much as possible, to make it easier for people to help you out. You should never have a `try/catch` that just eats an exception. Remove the repetition by making `x1/y1`, `x2/y2`, etc. a collection of points and iterating over them. And get rid of commented-out code!